# Sencha touch 2 load store and associated store with nested JSON

Tags: json, associations, sencha-touch-2, store

I've started creating a Sencha Touch 2 app that has two models defined, Change and Configuration. A Change belongsTo a Configuration. Both of the models also have a store setup. On the Changes store I have a proxy setup to request data that comes back in JSON format. The JSON data has a Change with a nested configuration. The Change loads just fine but when I try and get the associated Configuration from the Change instance it isn't working.

I've defined the models like this:

Change model:

```
Ext.define('Changes.model.Change', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    xtype: 'changemodel',

    config: {
        fields: [ 
            {name:'id', type:'int'},
            {name:'changeId', type:'string'},
            {name:'briefDescription', type:'string'},
            {name:'configuration_id', type:'int'}
        ],
        associations: [{
            type:'belongsTo', 
            model:'Changes.model.Configuration',
            primaryKey: 'id',
            foreignKey: 'configuration_id',
            associationKey: 'configurations'
        }],
    },
});
```

Configuration Model:

```
Ext.define('Changes.model.Configuration', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    xtype: 'configurationmodel',
    config: {
        fields: [
             { name: 'id', type: 'int'},
             { name: 'longName', type: 'string' },
             { name: 'ciName', type: 'string' },
            ],
        hasMany: {model: 'Change', name: 'changes'}
    }
});
```

Each model has a store.

Changes store:

```
Ext.define('Changes.store.Changes', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    requires: 'Changes.model.Change',
    config: {
        model: 'Changes.model.Change',  
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: 'services/changes.php',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                rootProperty: 'changes'
            }
        },
        sorters: [{ property: 'briefDescription', direction: 'ASC'}],
    }
});
```

Configurations store:

```
Ext.define('Changes.store.Configurations', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    requires: ['Ext.data.proxy.LocalStorage'],
    config: {
        model: 'Changes.model.Configuration',
        grouper: {
                sortProperty: "ciName",
                direction: "DESC",
                groupFn: function (record) {
                    return record.get('ciName')[0];
                }
           },
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: 'services/configurationItems.php',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                rootProperty: 'configurationItems'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

My JSON that is being returned from `services/changes.php` looks like this:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "changes": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "changeId": "XYZ19178263",
            "briefDescription": "Loaded from Proxy",
            "configuration_id": 3,
            "configurations": [
                {
                    "id": "3",
                    "longName": "999-99_-_windows_7_desktop.Computer.Windows",
                    "ciName": "999-99_-_windows_7_desktop"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

In the browser's console I can issue the following commands:

```
Changes.myStore = Ext.getStore('Changes');
Changes.myStore.load();
Changes.record = Changes.myStore.findRecord('id', '1');
Changes.record.getAssociatedData()
```

The last command will return an object with a Configuration object inside but all of the field values show `null` except for `id` which appears to be set to a random value:

```
Object
Configuration: Object
ciName: null
id: "ext-record-11"
longName: null
```

Can anyone see why the nested `Configuration` instance in my JSON isn't being saved? And should the nested `Configuration` instance in the JSON be added to the `Configurations` store automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly this just doesn't work. Appears to be a shortcoming of the framework. You can't load and save associated (aggregated/nested) objects. You need to flatten out your structure and then associate objects in code yourself.

So for example... your JSON would then be...

```
{
"success": true,
"changes": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "changeId": "XYZ19178263",
        "briefDescription": "Loaded from Proxy"
    }
]
```

}

And a second JSON file/response as follows:

```
    {

    "success": true,
    "configurations": [
                {
                    "id": "3",
                    "longName": "999-99_-_windows_7_desktop.Computer.Windows",
                    "ciName": "999-99_-_windows_7_desktop",
                    "change_id": 1
                }
            ]
    }
```

Comment: Can you give me an example or link to documentation that explains how I could associate objects in code myself?

Comment: Since I'm specifying an associated model in the association definition it seems like loading the two stores would automatically build the associations to any records with matching keys (where a change has a foreignKey to a configuration). Do I really need to associate the objects myself?

Comment: No, it won't automatically associate them for you.  The way you do it is this: you have 2 views/screens. The first one has a list of Change objects. The second view/screen shows a list of Configuration items (which are associated with a Change).  When a user taps on a Change in the first screen, you handle the event as follows: 1) Get the id of the Change item the user selected, say you call it selected_change_id;  then 2) Filter the secondary Configurations store by using "change_id = selected_change_id";   and finally 3) Show the second view/screen

Comment: BTW if you don't specify "@Tinashe" I don't get notification of your comments

Comment: This answer is not correct. You can definitely get related models in Sencha Touch.

Answer (score 2):

Tinashe's answer is not correct. You can certainly get nested models.

You have your associations backward with respect to your JSON, however.

```
 "changes": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "changeId": "XYZ19178263",
            "briefDescription": "Loaded from Proxy",
            "configuration_id": 3,
            "configurations": [
                {
                    "id": "3",
                    "longName": "999-99_-_windows_7_desktop.Computer.Windows",
                    "ciName": "999-99_-_windows_7_desktop"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

means a change hasMany configurations, but you are saying it belongsTo it. This is the correct JSON:

```
 "changes": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "changeId": "XYZ19178263",
            "briefDescription": "Loaded from Proxy",
            "configuration_id": 3,
            "configuration": 
                {
                    "id": "3",
                    "longName": "999-99_-_windows_7_desktop.Computer.Windows",
                    "ciName": "999-99_-_windows_7_desktop"
                }

        }
    ]
```

Either way, you need to set getterName (setterName if you like too) on the relationship:

```
associations: [{
            type:'belongsTo', 
            model:'Changes.model.Configuration',
            primaryKey: 'id',
            foreignKey: 'configuration_id',
            associationKey: 'configuration',
            getterName:'getConfiguration'
        }]
```

Then after the store loads, you can call myChangeModel.getConfiguration();